# Flutter math expression and polish characters

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, tex

I need to include a mathematical expression in my Flutter application.
I found the package flutter_tex, example:

```
                    child: TeXView(
                      teXHTML: r"$$Pole\ trójkąta = \frac{1}{2}ah$$",
                      loadingWidget: Center(
                         child: Text("Kalkulacja"),
                      ),
```

It's working, but polish letter 'ą' looks different like in other font.
Any ideas to add something to indicate it is polish text ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting everything between $$ and rendering engine is trying to render everything I would suggest you go like this by using `renderingEngine: TeXViewRenderingEngine.mathjax()`.

```
r"Pole trójkąta = \(\frac{1}{2}ah\) <br>"
or escape that particular text like
r" $$Pole\ \text{trójkąta} = \frac{1}{2}ah$$"
```